# React Native JavaScript Emoji Regex Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I am using **React Native 0.64.0**. I wrote this little program/function in Pure JavaScript:

```js
const text = ""
if (text.match(/\p{Emoji}/gu) != null) {
    if (text.match(/\p{Emoji}/gu).length*2 == text.length && text.match(/\p{Emoji}/gu).length > 0 && text.length/2 <= 3) {
    console.log(text)
    }
}
```

In Pure JavaScript it worked just as a I wanted it. So now I thought: Let's implement this in my React Native Chat App. I did everything the same and build this in a useEffect() function (at first for testing if it will work):

```js
const text = ""
if (text.match(/\p{Emoji}/gu) != null) {
    if (text.match(/\p{Emoji}/gu).length*2 == text.length && text.match(/\p{Emoji}/gu).length > 0 && text.length/2 <= 3) {
    console.log(text)
    }
}
```

And than there was something weird. I didn't get the  as a output - I got nothing.

So I changed a little bit and only tried this:

```js
console.log("".match(/\p{Emoji}/gu))
```

At first with a pure Javascript file and than in React Native and:

- In Plain Javascript it worked just fine and the output was: `[""]`
- In React Native it didn't work. The output was this: `null`

So the problem I am facing to right now is following:

Emoji Regex doesn't work as I want it to in React Native. The same statements, function and programs don't work in React Native but in Javascript they do.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

possibly the `u` flag is a problem since it tells regex to match unicode

this worked for me

```
console.log("".match(/(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/g))
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is a problem. If I have something like this: ░ it will also say it is an emoji. This is a behavior I can't accept, because it would destroy my app Design. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: What was a good question?

Comment: I think I used an external library because of the regular upates the emojis get